# Regex match with capturing group excluding specific characters and looking for the last occurrence based on later characters

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I apologize beforehand for the jumbled mess that is the title but that's the shortest way I could think to describe what I'm trying to do.

I'm reading a file that has multiple lines of text that I'm looping through and I'm trying to use regex to get a substring from each line. These lines will start with the word "name: " then have some series of letters and possibly hyphens. After that, there may be a '#' followed by digits, or a '-' followed by digits, or a new line. I only want to capture the letters and possible hyphens. Below is what I've tried with input, output, and intended output. This regex is being run in linux bash script

| regex |
| --- |
| name: (.[^\#\r\n\d]*) |

| input |
| --- |
| name: foo-bar#2.3.2 |
| name: bar-foo-4.2 |
| name: foobar |
| name: far-far |

| captured outputs |
| --- |
| foo-bar |
| bar-foo- |
| foobar |
| far-far |

| Intended outputs |
| --- |
| foo-bar |
| bar-foo |
| foobar |
| far-far |

Code sample:

```
fileRegex="name: (.[^\\#\r\n\d]*)"
for i in "${fileList[@]}"
do
    if [[$i =~ $fileRegex ]]; then
        fixedLine="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        echo "$fixedLine"
    fi
done
```

From the table, the offending instance is "name: bar-foo-4.2" which should only output "bar-foo" but instead is outputting "bar-foo-". What I'm trying to figure out is how to stop capturing when there is a "-" followed by any digits, but also to maintain the outputs of all the other examples.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. **You start it, and then we help. We don't write it for you.** Show us the actual code that you've tried, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Comment: @AndyLester I'm not asking anyone to write anything for me, I was actually editing to add a code block but the regex that I need help with was already in the original post. It doesn't help that people are editing the question out from under me and changing what's supposed to be in there. I didn't think the code would be needed originally because the output of my code is exactly what I get when I run the regex with the inputs I provided in the question on regex101

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `bash` you may try this code:

```sh
declare -a arr=([0]="name: foo-bar#2.3.2" [1]="name: bar-foo-4.2" [2]="name: foobar" [3]="name: far-far")
fileRegex='name: ([[:alpha:]]+(-[[:alpha:]]+)*)'
for s in "${arr[@]}"; do
   [[ $s =~ $fileRegex ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
done
```

**Output:**

```sh
foo-bar
bar-foo
foobar
far-far
```

**RegEx Explained:**

- `name:` : Match `"name: "`
- `(`: First capture group start

  - `[[:alpha:]]+`: Match 1+ alphabets
  - (-[[:alpha:]]+)*`: Separated with hyphens match 0 or more 1+ alpha character substring
- `)`: First capture group end